# Unexpected dangling '_' in '_gaq'

Tags: javascript, browser, google-analytics, jslint

I'm trying to validate my Google Analytics code using JSLint but I get a lot of error messages:

The code:

```
/*global document */
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-24389816-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function () {
    var s,
        ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' === document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
}());
```

Error messages:

> Problem at line 2 character 5:
>   Unexpected dangling '_' in '_gaq'.
>
> var _gaq = _gaq || [];
>
> Problem at line 2 character 12:
>   Unexpected dangling '_' in '_gaq'.
>
> var _gaq = _gaq || [];
>
> Problem at line 3 character 1:
>   Unexpected dangling '_' in '_gaq'.
>
> _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-24389816-1']);
>
> Problem at line 4 character 1:
>   Unexpected dangling '_' in '_gaq'.
>
> _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

What's wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3039587/353278

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The jslint default settings do not allow an underscore at the beginning of variable names. This is because in other languages, it implies a private variable, something which JavaScript does not support.

To remove the warnings, you can add `nomen: true` to the options of jslint. Otherwise, you will have to tolerate the warnings.

As far as I'm aware, Google does not offer a way to rename this variable at this time.

Comment: I've checked "Tolerate dangling _ in identifiers" option.

Comment: Javascript does support private variables through the use of closures.

Comment: @magritte I think pete was implying that JavaScript does not support the creation of the private variable with an _ underscore.

Answer (score 1):

For JSLint or JSHint, set `nomen: false` to ignore this warning.

Comment: It's /*jslint nomen: true*/

Comment: False worked for me.  True didn't

Comment: change nomen to false works for me too