# In sublime text 3 jslint, how to enable the "Tolerate dangling _ in identifiers" (nomen) option?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, jslint

I found a very [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039587/jslint-reports-unexpected-dangling-character-in-an-underscore-prefixed-variabl) to suppress jslint waring about "_".

How do I implement the

> [JSLint reports "Unexpected dangling" character in an underscore prefixed variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039587/jslint-reports-unexpected-dangling-character-in-an-underscore-prefixed-variabl)

in Sublime Text 3?

Comment: There are two Sublime Text JSLint plugins. Are you using the [Deridder plugin](https://github.com/darrenderidder/Sublime-JSLint) or the [fbzhong pluging](https://github.com/fbzhong/sublime-jslint)?

Comment: I am using this one: https://github.com/devdoc/SublimeLinter-jslint